# Universal covers of the rotation group

Tags: algebraic-topology

Is it correct to say that the universal cover of the rotation group SO(n) is always a double cover? Does this hold when we generalise to SO(p,q)?

Comment: By «always» you mean «for all $n$»? For $n=2$ the cover is certainly not double.

Comment: Have a look at the [Wikipedia spin group page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_group).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is, equivalently: is it true that the rotation groups $SO(p, q)$ always have fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}_2$? The answer is no. Among the definite ones, $SO(2)$ has fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}$ and $SO(1)$ is a point, so has trivial fundamental group (this becomes important in the next paragraph). $SO(n)$ has fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}_2$ for $n \ge 3$.

Among the indefinite ones, $SO(p, q)$ is not connected in general so we should really be talking about its identity component. This deformation retracts onto its maximal compact, which is $SO(p) \times SO(q)$, and hence its fundamental group depends on whether $p$ and $q$ are $1, 2$, or greater according to the above. For example, when $p = q = 2$ it is $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$. Generically, if $p, q \ge 3$, it is $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.